# How to construct second promise list from first promise list and iterate

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have a category list. I need to look if the category ids are available in the db if it is then insert those ids into another table
I have two promises list. what i want is call second promise list after 1st one finish iterate

```
// category ids as follows
let categoryIds = [['cat1','cat2', 'cat3'],['cat4','cat5', 'cat6']];

// insert promise
let insertCategoriesPromiseList = [];

// then iterate through the array and get categories from db

categoryIds.filter((categories) => {

   let isCategoryAvailablePromises = [];

   categories.filter((catId) => {
      isCategoryAvailablePromises.push(checkForCategory(catId));
   })

   Promise.all(isCategoryAvailablePromises)
    .then(data => {
      // if all the cat ids are in the db then insert those cat ids
      // into another table
      insertCategoriesPromiseList.push(insertCatIds(data.cat1, data.cat2, data.cat3))
    })

});

function checkForCategory(catId){
   const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
     db.any('select categoryName from category where ...')
      .then(data=>{
         // if all the categories are available return 
         resolve(data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
         reject(e);
      })
   })
   return promise;
}

function insertCatIds(catId1, catId2, catId3){
   const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
     db.one('insert into products ...')
      .then(data=>{
         // if all the categories are available return 
         resolve(data);
      })
      .catch(e => {
         reject(e);
      })
   })
   return promise;
}
```

I want to execute below after creating the full `insertCategoriesPromiseList` how should I do this...

```
Promise.all(insertCategoriesPromiseList)
 .then(p => {

 })
 .catch()
```

Comment: why use filter and push when you are not filtering? `let isCategoryAvailablePromises = categories.map(catId => checkForCategory(catId))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rewrite it like this:

```
function checkForCategory(catId){
     return db.any('select categoryName from category where ...')
      .then(data=>{
         //massage data if needed
         return data;//return cat id!
      });
}

function insertCatIds(catId1, catId2, catId3){
     return db.one('insert into products ...')
      .then(data=>{
         //massage data if needed
         return data;
      });
}

let load = ['catid1', 'catid2'].map(id => checkForCategory(id));
Promise.all(load).then((...ids) => insertCatIds.apply(this, ids));
```

Notice I didn't write `new Promise((resolve, reject) => ...` because [Promise.prototype.then()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) actually returns a `Promise`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: how does this address `second promise list after 1st one finish iterate`

Comment: @Bravo he wants to call the second promise after the first one is resolved!

Comment: no ... he wants to call a "second promise list" after the "first one finishes iterating"